# Why creating git branch doesn't copy all files?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-pull

`git branch` shows me that I'm on *master*.
I write `git checkout -b newbranch`.
`git branch` shows me that I'm on newly created branch *newbranch*.
I write `git pull` and get the following error:

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> newbranch
```

I guess that was because I couldn't pull from a branch that I only just created. So I write `git pull origin master` and get a million files that differ between branches *master* and *newbranch* (taking my full console so I can't see the beginning of the error) with the following ending:

```
Please move or remove them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

I don't understand why branch *newbranch* isn't an exact copy of *master*. From what I read when I create a new branch it starts from the same commit as the branch I was on. I just wanted to make `git pull` to make sure all files are exactly the same as on master. If the new branch isn't the exact copy of the branch it was copied from, I don't know where all the files were taken from.

**Edit:**
As everyone mentioned, the problem was that my local master was different than remote master. So I had to do:

```
git checkout master
git branch -d newbranch
git fetch --all
# change permision issues with chmod and chown
git reset --hard origin/master
git checkout -b newbranch
```

Comment: You created your `newbranch` of your *local* master branch. If you received changes when doing `git pull origin master` later, then apparently your local master branch was outdated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the most important properties of `git` is that `git` is a distributed version control system. This means that your local branch doesn't need to be in sync of your remote branch.

In your particular case, you have a `master` on your machine. When you do `git checkout -b newbranch`, you created a new branch which is the same as your `master` on your machine.

However there is also a `master` on the remote machine whose name is `origin` (perhaps GitHub if you use it). So when you do `git pull origin master`, your are merging your local `newbranch` with the remote `origin/master` instead of your local `master`. I think your case here is that your local `master` has merge conflicts with `origin/master`.

**What you should do**

To create a new branch

```
git checkout -b newbranch # create local newbranch from local master
git push --set-upstream origin newbranch # push your local newbranch to origin/newbranch
```

You also want to keep your local master in sync with `origin/master`

```
git checkout master
git pull # and solve merge conflicts
```

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. Good answer; in agreement with what I said: master branch is not up to date with origin/master. Keep up the good work :)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to **see** the difference; consider using one of the following commands:

```
git diff master         # diff with local master branch
git diff origin/master  # diff with master on origin
git diff master --stat  # diff with local master branch (but show list of files only)
```

The reason why you have many differences is probably that your **master** branch is not up to date with **origin/master**. Your branch **newbranch** is indeed supposed to be an exact "copy" of your master branch. `git diff master` should be empty.